# Two SSL apps - WebAPI doesn't run

Tags: ssl, iis, .net-core

I have two applications in my solution. One is WebAPI and the second is Razor MVC app.
Now, WebApi application was created in VisualStudio 2017 and then migrated to VS2019 (.netcore 3)
WebApi worked.

When I tried to run Razor app, my Firefox was giving me errors saying that it **could not establish secure connection** with code: **PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR**
So after some digging, I have removed all localhost certificates and reinstalled IISExpress. Razor app started working. But my WebApi still won't start. My WebApi is published on my local IIS server, but it won't start with the same error: PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

So one app from solution works and the other doesn't. Does anyone have any idea how to work it out?

Comment: What are the URLs for each and how did you configure them on IIS/IIS Express? Multiple HTTPS sites can live peacefully with each other only if you have valid certificate mappings and no conflict, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Comment: Multiple site is not a problem here. Because I have WebApi published on local IIS and just want to start it. I gave the other application to show that the other one can be run, but WebAPI cannot. This is something to do with certifications, but I really don't know what.

Comment: Have you set trusted certificate and enable Server name indication for both websites? Otherwise, ssl handshake would probably failed and one of them would return wrong certificate. Besides, did you see something wrong in httperr log?

Comment: OK, I think that I figured it out. It was server bindings. https binding didn't have certificate assigned.